# Почему идет рассинхронизация анимации?

Tags: jquery, анимация, settimeout

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  func();

  function func() {
    $('.slide').each(function(i) {
      delay = i * 3000;
      $(this).delay(delay).show('slide', {
        direction: 'left'
      }, 1000).delay(2000).hide('slide', {
        direction: 'right'
      }, 1000);
    });
    setTimeout(func, 9000);
  }

});
```

```css
#slider_viewport {
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
 }
 .slide {
   background-color: #fff; /* добавил для демонстрации */
   display: none;
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="slider_viewport">
  <li class="slide">first slide</li>
  <li class="slide">second slide</li>
  <li class="slide">third slide</li>
</ul>
```

Если сделать анимацию `show + delay + hide == 3000` т.е равную задержке появления следующего слайда, все работает ровно, но если анимацию увеличить по времени, чтобы слайды шли один за другим, без промежутка, появляется рассинхронизация.

Как правильно выставить `delay` у `setTimeout()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  var $li = $(".slide"),
    len = $li.length,
    num = 0;
  (function func() {
    $li.eq(num).delay(2E3).show("slide", {
      direction: "left"
    }, 1E3, func).delay(2E3).hide("slide", {
      direction: "right"
    }, 1E3);
    num = ++num % len
  }())
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#slider_viewport {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.slide {
  list-style: none;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.a {
  display: block;
  background-color: #FF00FF;
}
.b {
  background-color: #00BFFF;
}
.c {
  background-color: #FFFF00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<ul id="slider_viewport">
  <li class="slide a">first slide</li>
  <li class="slide b">second slide</li>
  <li class="slide c">third slide</li>
</ul>
```

для такого слайдера таймер излишен